# EntityManager lifecycle and persistent client-server-communication

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

we are developing an (JavaSE-) application which communicates to many clients via persistent tcp-connections. The client connects, performs some/many  operations (which are updated to a SQL-Database) and closes the application / disconnects from server. We're using Hibernate-JPA and manage the EntityManager-lifecycle on our own, using a ThreadLocal-variable. Actually we create a new EntityManager-instance on every client-request which works fine so far. Recently we profiled a bit and we found out that hibernate performs a SELECT-query to the DB before every UPDATE-statement. That is because our entities are in detached-state and every new EntityManager attaches the entity to the persistence context first. This leads to a massive SQL-overhead when the server is under load (because we have an write-heavy application)and we try to eliminate that leak.

- First, we thought about 2nd-Level-Cache. However, we discovered that hibernate invalidates it's Query- and Collection-Caches whenever a new item is added or removed.
- On second thought, we evaluate whether to keep an EntityManager up as long as the client is logged in on the server. But I wonder if this is a "best practice", because there are some drawbacks: thread-safety, managing-overhead of the EntityManager-instances, etc.

In short: we are looking for a way to get rid of those SELECT-statements before every UPDATE. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to get rid of `select` statements when reattaching detached entities is to use Hibernate-specific `update()` operation instead of `merge()`.

`update()` unconditionally runs an `update` SQL statement and makes detached object persistent. If persistent object with the same identifier already exists in a session, it throws an exception. Thus, it's a good choice when you are sure that:

1. Detached object contains modified state that should be saved in the database
2. Saving that state is the main goal of opening a session for that request (i.e. there were no other operations that loaded entity with the same id in that session)

In JPA 2.0 you can access Hibernate-specific operations as follows:

```
em.unwrap(Session.class).update(o);
```

**See also:**

- [11.6. Modifying detached objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached)

Comment: Sounds very useful for us. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to use [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) for the update statements. I've successfully used it in my 'write-heavy' application.